# How can I get the value from textfield if it appears to be blank after I click another button?

Tags: php, html, post, textinput

The price shows up without problems after i clicked the 'order' submit button 
   but it cannot get the value of price anymore once i click the 'pay' button. 
   How can i get the value from the textfield without losing is value after i 
   click the value. Or some sort of saving it if  that's possible.
    [form sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfhoj.jpg)

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['myorder'])){

    $order=trim($_POST['myorder']);

    if($order=="wintermelon"){
    $price = 100 * $_POST['qty'] ;

    if($order=="taro"){
    $price = 110 * $_POST['qty'] ;

    }
    if($order=="caramel"){
    $price = 110 * $_POST['qty'] ;

}


}
}

if(isset($_POST['pay'])){

    **$price=trim($_POST['price']);**

    if(!empty($_POST['cash']) ){

    $cash=trim($_POST['cash']);

    if($cash >= $price){
        $change = $cash - $price;
    }
    if($cash < $price){

        $insuf = "<span style='font-size: 15px;'>*You have insufficient 
cash.</span>";
    }
}else{
    $errorMessage= "<span style='font-size: 15px;'>*Please insert cash.
</span>";
}

}
?>

//HTML code:

<form method="post" action="<?php echo 
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" id="my form">
<h3 style="color: #FFF;">Order</h3>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <input type="text" name="placeorder" id="placeorder" class="form-
control" value="<?php echo htmlentities($order)?>" disabled>


    </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="mango"><font color="white">Quantity</font></label>
        <input type="number" class="col-xs-2" name="qty" id="qty1" min="1" 
max="10" value="" >


</div>
</div>
<h5 style="color: #FFF;">Price</h5>
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" value='<?php echo htmlentities($price)?>' disabled>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">

<input type="submit" name="addorder" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Order">
</div>
</div>
<h3 style="color: #FFF;">Order</h3>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <input type="text" name="placeorder" id="placeorder" class="form-
control" value="<?php echo htmlentities($order)?>" disabled>


    </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="mango"><font color="white">Quantity</font></label>
        <input type="number" class="col-xs-2" name="qty" id="qty1" min="1" 
max="10" value="" >


</div>
</div>
<h5 style="color: #FFF;">Price</h5>
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" value='<?php echo 
htmlentities($price)?>' disabled>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">

<input type="submit" name="addorder" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Order">
</div>
</div>

<h5 style="color: #FFF;">Cash</h5>
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<input type="text" name="cash" class="form-control" <?php echo 
htmlentities($cash)?>>
<?php echo $insuf ?>
<?php echo $errorMessage ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
**<input type="submit" name="pay" class="btn btn-primary" value="Pay">**
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use `$_GET`

Comment: I don't think you need htmlentities in <?php echo htmlentities($price)?>